# Highlight all occurrences of a string in Word using VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I would like to highlight all occurrences of a given string in Microsoft Word 2010 using VSTO.

So far, I've managed to set the foreground color for the matches using the `Find` facility:

```
Word.Find find = Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Find;
find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndexBi = Word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
find.Execute(FindText: "dog", MatchCase: false, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

However, I would like to set the highlight for the matches, such as in the screenshot below:

[image: highlight word]

Comment: Recording in VBA suggests that you set the highlight colour by setting using Application.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex to one of the wdColorIndex members (e.g. wdYellow), and that you apply the Highlight colour in a Replace using find.Replacement.Highlight = True. Are those available via VSTO?

Comment: @bibadia: Thanks, that worked :-) If you copy your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: thanks, done - I usually find it quicker to check the VBA side but prefer not to post an Answer unless I'm sure the same option is available via the PIAs etc.

Comment: I came across some VBA snippets that I couldn't port, but yours worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the highlight colour by setting using

```
Application.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
```

to one of the wdColorIndex members (e.g. wdYellow)

Apply the Highlight colour in a Replace using

```
find.Replacement.Highlight = True
```

Answer (score 3):

If one wants temporary highlighting, one may use the [`HitHighlight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845691%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method instead:

```
Word.Find find = Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Find;
find.HitHighlight(
    FindText: "dog",
    MatchCase: false,
    HighlightColor: Word.WdColor.wdYellow);
```