# How to highlight a matching text in the active word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am creating a C# windows form application and I want to search for a string in the currently opened word document and if it matches I want to highlight the text in the word document. Also I want to know whether is that possible to show a messagebox at the word document side showing a message?

Below is the code I have written

```
string matchString = "This is the text I want to match";
        public void testMethod()
        {
            Object wordObject = null;
            Application word = null;
            object missObj = Missing.Value;
            object readOnly  = false;
            object FullPath = null;
            Document document = null;

            try
            {
                wordObject = (Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

                word = (Application)wordObject;
                word.Visible = true;
                //word.ScreenUpdating = false;

                FullPath = word.ActiveDocument.FullName;

                    document = word.Documents.Open(ref FullPath, ref missObj, ref readOnly, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
                    document.Activate();

                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range docRange in document.Sentences)
                    {
                        string xx = docRange.Text.Trim();
                        if (docRange.Text.Trim().Equals(matchString,
                           StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            docRange.HighlightColorIndex =
                              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
                            docRange.Font.ColorIndex =
                              Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes, you can search for text and color or highlight it. My advice would be to first try this in the Word UI, using the "Advanced Find" (rather than the Find in the task pane). Once you feel comfortable with that dialog box and the result, record performing the Find in a Word macro. That will give you the basic objects, properties and methods. Then do an Internet search on finding in Word, with C#. There are a multitude of examples, both here and on the MSDN site. A couple of examples https://stackoverflow.com/q/4016960/3077495, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21063419/3077495

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and Highlight issue in word addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291072/find-and-highlight-issue-in-word-addin)

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for the explanation. My application is a external C# applicaiton. I am not developing a word addin. Is it possible to highlight and show a message in word using a external application?